# Mismatching between dates mongoose database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I tried to stored date within mongodatabse database, there's difference between the server and local, I got always date - 1 hour within the server.
Otherwise, I noticed a strange thing happened within the local, and here's an example :

1. Get Object from the front contain a date :

   console.dir(req.body);

> { 
>       title: 'a',
>       date: '2018-01-20T00:00:28+01:00',
>       message:'a',
>       status: 'inDirectly',
>       active: true 
>   }

2. Create a new record based on moongose schema that contain a date type :

   let newCommunication = new Communication(req.body);
3. Then display the record like this :

   console.dir(newCommunication._doc);

   and I got :

> { _id:
>       ObjectID {
>          _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
>          id: Buffer [ 90, 98, 3, 99, 240, 231, 66, 2, 16, 200, 27, 192 ] 
>       },
>       active: true,
>       status: 'inDirectly',
>       message: 'a',
>       date: 2018-01-19T23:00:28.000Z,
>       title: 'a' }

4. After that I saved, but in the database I got the real date, I mean the 
   first and the correct one.

   [image]

   What's that mean ?
   And What I should do to correct that within the server ?

Comment: Both dates are same. `2018-01-19T23:00:28.000Z` = `2018-01-20T00:00:28+01:00`

Comment: How can eliminate +01:00 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date